# How to hide the all the content until the user searches for a specific item in this table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I want to create a table with hidden contents from the user but is available if they typed the specific items. So, basically, I just want to have a search bar as the only thing displayed.

Here is what I already have, and this is from w3schools:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    #myInput {
      background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
      background-position: 10px 10px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 16px;
      padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      margin-bottom: 12px;
    }
    
    #myTable {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      font-size: 18px;
    }
    
    #myTable th,
    #myTable td {
      text-align: left;
      padding: 12px;
    }
    
    #myTable tr {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
    
    #myTable tr.header,
    #myTable tr:hover {
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h2>My Customers</h2>

  <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

  <table id="myTable">
    <tr class="header">
      <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
      <th style="width:40%;">Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
      <td>Sweden</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Island Trading</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
      <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
      <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>North/South</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Paris specialites</td>
      <td>France</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
      input = document.getElementById("myInput");
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      table = document.getElementById("myTable");
      tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
      for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        if (td) {
          txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
          if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
          } else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
          }
        }
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

And lastly, how would I be able to add a clickable link on an item? I've seen a website with those features and I tried to find the answer on my own but can't. I'm also a beginner and have zero background in coding, although I've learned quite fast these past few weeks. So I would appreciate it if you use will use words I can understand.

If you want to know what I'm gonna do with this is I'm planning to build a free books blog where people can just search their favorite author or book title and it will appear on the search bar if it's available. 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: If I may ask one more thing, is it practical to use this as a search filter for thousands of books? Or is there a better way? I don't want to waste more of your time, but if I can just ask where to go next or what  I need to learn to build a search filter for thousands of books? Because I believe if I use this code, I will have to enter the new information manually everytime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I would do it. I tried adding as many comments as I could to explain why I did some things. There are some in the HTML, the CSS, and the JS code. Feel free to ask any question.

```js
// When the DOM (HTML structure) is ready
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  // First, we can create references to DOM elements on page start,
  // which we'll reuse instead of looking them up every time we perform a search.
  // As a convention, I like variables holding DOM elements to start with $,
  // so that I know what I'm dealing with in the blink of an eye 
  var $input = document.getElementById("myInput"),
      $table = document.getElementById("myTable"),
      // Only select the <tr>s inside the <tbody> (double $ -> multiple elements)
      $$tr   = $table.querySelectorAll("tbody tr");

  // Add the normalized name as a property to each tr, so that you don't have
  // to compute that every time when performing a search
  for (var i = 0; i < $$tr.length; i++) {
    $$tr[i].normalizedValue = normalizeStr( $$tr[i].querySelector("td").innerText );
  }
  // When typing or pasting text, perform a search
  $input.addEventListener("input", performSearch);

  function performSearch() {
    var filter = normalizeStr(this.value);
    for (var i = 0; i < $$tr.length; i++) {
      var isMatch = $$tr[i].normalizedValue.includes(filter);
      // Toggle a 'visible' class
      $$tr[i].classList[isMatch ? "add" : "remove"]("visible");
    }
  }

  // Creating a reusable function will allow us to make
  // changes to it only in one place 
  function normalizeStr(str) {
    return str.toUpperCase().trim();
  }
});
```

```css
/* ... untouched CSS ... */ *{box-sizing:border-box}#myInput{background-image:url(/css/searchicon.png);background-position:10px 10px;background-repeat:no-repeat;width:100%;font-size:16px;padding:12px 20px 12px 40px;border:1px solid #ddd;margin-bottom:12px}#myTable{border-collapse:collapse;width:100%;border:1px solid #ddd;font-size:18px}#myTable td,#myTable th{text-align:left;padding:12px}#myTable tr{border-bottom:1px solid #ddd}

#myTable thead tr, /* notice the use of thead */
#myTable tr:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

#myTable tbody tr {
  display: none; /* Hide rows by default */
}

#myTable tbody tr.visible {
  display: table-row; /* Show them when they match */
}
```

```html
<h2>My Customers</h2>

<!-- Try not using `on...=""` attributes. Separating HTML and JS is better practice -->
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search for names" title="Type in a name" />

<table id="myTable">
  <!-- Use <thead> and <tbody> to separate data from headers -->
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
      <th style="width:40%;">Country</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr> <td><a href="http://example.com/">Alfreds Futterkiste</a></td> <td>Germany</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td><a href="http://example.com/">Berglunds snabbkop</a></td> <td>Sweden</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td><a href="http://example.com/">Island Trading</a></td> <td>UK</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td><a href="http://example.com/">Koniglich Essen</a></td> <td>Germany</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td><a href="http://example.com/">Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</a></td> <td>Canada</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td><a href="http://example.com/">Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</a></td> <td>Italy</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td><a href="http://example.com/">North/South</a></td> <td>UK</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td><a href="http://example.com/">Paris specialites</a></td> <td>France</td> </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Really nice and well commented answer ;) `+1`

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for your time answering my question in a such a detailed way. Although it is still beyond my knowledge to understand the script you did there. But I do appreciate it and I know i'll get it one of these days after a couple more tutorials. It worked though, and I believe it made it all function smoother. And one last thing if i may, how do I add links to it?

Comment: For example, I've searched an author, say, Kafka, then I want it to be clickable so I will be redirected to it. I've tried to guess how I'd fix it, but it doesn't work. Putting the standard <a href=""> ruins the code somehow?

Comment: If I may ask one more thing, is it practical to use this as a search filter for thousands of books? Or is there a better way? I don't want to waste more of your time, but if I can just ask where to go next or what  I need to learn to build a search filter for thousands of books? Because I believe if I use this code, I will have to enter the new information manually everytime?

Comment: I updated my answer to add `<a href>` to the names, it seems to work as expected. Did your HTML look like that? About the thousands of books: It depends on how many thousands but if you want to go next level, you could use a database _(MySQL, Postgres, or MongoDB...)_, and server-side code _(PHP, Java, Python, or even good old JavaScript, using NodeJS...)_. This will allow you to have a very light HTML page, and perform the search server-side as the user types, using Ajax. These are some keywords, you'll find plenty of tutorials out there. And if you get stuck, don't hesitate to come back here

Comment: Wow! It worked well! Thank you so much, you've been very helpful more than you will believe! I've been searching for these solutions on my own for a few days now, and never asked first. My mistake. I learned a lot today. Thank you @blex. I'll be sure to pass on the same act to others someday

Comment: Hi blex, I didn't realize I have a few more concerns if I could still have some of your time. How can I tweak the script so that it will also show the countries if it's what the user is filtering? And also, can I add a "no results found" with a simple addition of a script?

Comment: @ivmaxifa Here is an example where the same text field is used to search for either a name or a country, and shows "No results found" if that's the case: [Demo 1](https://jsfiddle.net/0fu1g7xe/). And another one, with the same thing, but using a separate `<select>` field for the country: [Demo 2](https://jsfiddle.net/zqef45u6/). Hope this helps

Comment: Just got back, but wow sir, thank you so much once again. For now, this is all perfect!

Comment: Hello @blex, I've really used this tool since the past few weeks. Though now I have another request please, if I you can still help me? I've tried tweaking it on my own  but it's not working. How do I make this a 3 column table that is all searchable?

Comment: Hey @ivmaxifa sure, which example in the above comment did you use? One field for all (demo 1), or separate fields (demo 2)?

Comment: Hi @blex, I used the first 1. Btw, the purpose of the additional column is to add "meta" search details. And for now, what I did is add a hidden p tag. It works like this
```
<td><a href="http://example.com/">Alfreds Futterkiste</a>
</td> 
<td>Germany
<p hidden>Lorem Ipsum</p>
</td> </tr>
```

That way, I can search for the "meta" words but it would show only the visible texts. I made it like this so people can use keywords even if it doesn't match the words exactly.

Answer (score 3):

You were almost there. Just add in the `css` the property `display: none` on your rows to hide them. You can then reappear them in javascript using the `diplay: table-row` property:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    #myInput {
      background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
      background-position: 10px 10px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 16px;
      padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      margin-bottom: 12px;
    }
    
    #myTable {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      font-size: 18px;
    }
    
    #myTable th,
    #myTable td {
      text-align: left;
      padding: 12px;
    }
    
    #myTable tr:not(.header) {
      display: none;   /* <-- Hide all items (but not header) on init */
    }
    
    #myTable tr {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
    
    #myTable tr.header,
    #myTable tr:hover {
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h2>My Customers</h2>

  <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

  <table id="myTable">
    <tr class="header">
      <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
      <th style="width:40%;">Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
      <td>Sweden</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Island Trading</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
      <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
      <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>North/South</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Paris specialites</td>
      <td>France</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
      input = document.getElementById("myInput");
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      table = document.getElementById("myTable");
      tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
      for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        if (td) {
          txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
          if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            tr[i].style.display = "table-row"; // <-- Show matching items
          } else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
          }
        }
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi that works so thank you so much! I didn't know putting the "display:none" will work there. Like i've said, I still have a lot to learn 